# What are NDF Files?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-administration, mdf, ldf

SQL Server uses `.mdf` for data files and `.ldf` for log files, but what are `.ndf` files?

What are the benefits of these files?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

From [Files and Filegroups Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179316.aspx)

**Secondary data files**

Secondary data files make up all the data files, other than the primary data file. Some databases may not have any secondary data files, while others have several secondary data files. **The recommended file name extension for secondary data files is .ndf.**

Also from [file extension NDF - Microsoft SQL Server secondary data file](http://www.file-extensions.org/ndf-file-extension-microsoft-sql-server-secondary-data-file)

See [Understanding Files and Filegroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189563.aspx)

> Secondary data files are optional, are
>   user-defined, and store user data.
>   Secondary files can be used to spread
>   data across multiple disks by putting
>   each file on a different disk drive.
>   Additionally, if a database exceeds
>   the maximum size for a single Windows
>   file, you can use secondary data files
>   so the database can continue to grow.
>
> The recommended file name extension
>   for secondary data files is .ndf.

/

> For example, three files, Data1.ndf,
>   Data2.ndf, and Data3.ndf, can be
>   created on three disk drives,
>   respectively, and assigned to the
>   filegroup fgroup1. A table can then be
>   created specifically on the filegroup
>   fgroup1. Queries for data from the
>   table will be spread across the three
>   disks; this will improve performance.
>   The same performance improvement can
>   be accomplished by using a single file
>   created on a RAID (redundant array of
>   independent disks) stripe set.
>   However, files and filegroups let you
>   easily add new files to new disks.

Comment: Today I learned that tempdb can also create NDF files and the number of files depends on the number of logical processors - see docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/tempdb-database?view=sql-server-ver15#physical-properties-of-tempdb-in-sql-server

Comment: has it always been like this? of was NDF introduced at some point?

Comment: What does user data mean here? Is it different from data in .MDF files?

Answer (score 10):

> Secondary data files are optional, are user-defined, and store user data. Secondary files can be used to spread data across multiple disks by putting each file on a different disk drive. Additionally, if a database exceeds the maximum size for a single Windows file, you can use secondary data files so the database can continue to grow.

Source: [MSDN: Understanding Files and Filegroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189563.aspx)

The recommended file name extension for secondary data files is `.ndf`, but this is not enforced.

Answer (score 3):

An NDF file is a user defined secondary database file of Microsoft SQL Server with an extension .ndf, which store user data. Moreover,  when the size of the database file growing automatically from its specified size, you can use .ndf file for extra storage and the .ndf file could be stored on a separate disk drive. Every NDF file uses the same filename as its corresponding MDF file. We cannot open an .ndf file in SQL Server Without attaching its associated .mdf file.

Comment: "Every NDF file uses the same filename as its corresponding MDF file" - this may be a convention, but isn't a requirement.