# How to change content of an NDF file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, file-type

I have a collection of NDF files each of which contains daily data. I want to change the content of this file, say, change the day and save it. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What is an NDF file? Or your meant MDF?

Comment: @ZoffDino I Meant NDF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707403/what-are-ndf-files

Comment: But what are you trying to do? Are you wanting to change the data that is in a filegroup? What does that have to do with changing the day? Filegroups don't store portions of a table. That is table partitioning.

Comment: @SeanLange Actually, this one is asked by a friend of mine and I am doing a research in his stead. He told me, he wanted to change the date and date is a data in the file group. I think I might be misunderstanding how NDF works so I wanted to ask it here. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah I would go back to your friend and ask what he is trying to do. Date doesn't belong to a file group, it is a datatype. It seems you need some clarity on what he is wanting to do so you can determine how to do it.